# How to use IIS 7 custom logging module and ETW tracing module

Tags: logging, iis-7, trace

I notice that IIS 7 has a custom logging module logcust.dll. It is said this module helps load your own custom logging module. But I can't find any information about how to use it. I opened this DLL and notice that it implements IHttpModule and register to all events but does nothing in event handlers.

Same question for another IIS ETW Module iisetw.dll.

Answer (score 1):

See here for a brief description of all the IIS modules:

- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-7-modules-overview/

See here for more on the Custom Logging Module:

- http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/579/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---custom-logging/
- http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpLogging

The Custom Logging Module controls the standard logging that you can configure via the IIS Manager interface.  You can technically customize this, providing your own logging implementation, but with IIS7 its recommended that you just create your own module instead.

The IIS ETW module is used for logging trace events to ETW.  Here's the documentation on ETW for IIS 6.  It basically works the same way for IIS7, but with more information included in the traces.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728367(WS.10).aspx

Here's how you turn tracing on for specific URLs:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpTracing

IIS7 also includes the Failed Request Tracing feature which allows you to collect the ETW traces for only specific requests - e.g. only failed requests.  This is what I normally use if I want to collect traces.